# Anaconda navigator doesn't launch any applications after update

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I updated anaconda after I had enough of the messages asking me to update.
since the update I can't launch jupyter notebook or any application from the anaconda navigator. I also updated the jupyter notebook to the last version available.
Uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled a new version from the anaconda website.

Still the same problem occurs. I don't get any error message so I don't have a clue.
Searched for a lot of solutions online but with no success.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I abandoned using the navigator years ago - and just go directly to whatever I want to open - and it works grand.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) and do a full uninstall using Anaconda-Clean. Then continue reading the docs about the proper installation procedure and how to update Anaconda (if needed).

Comment: Thank Peter. Tried it but still , The navigator doesn't work